# Accessing ViewBag properties using JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm assigning a list to the view bag like so:

```
ViewBag.MyArray = GetSomeIEnumerable();
```

On the client, I render the page and can access the elements from JS executed in *onload* by fix strings like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var output = "Info: @(ViewBag.MyArray["honka"]["ponka"])";
  alert(output);
}
```

However, I'm not clear on how to access the element if the indexes are specified as variables like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var honka = "honka";
  var ponka = "ponka";
  var output = "Info: @(ViewBag.MyArray[???][???])";
  alert(output);
}
```

I've tried escaping by backslash-quote, using it straight of and a few other variants but apparently I'm not getting the syntax right as I get errors like *variable not recognized in scope* and *missing closing parantesis*.

## Edit

```
<td>
  @(ViewBag.MyArray[a][b])
</td>
```

## Edit

I also added the *using* keyword at the top of both CS and CSHTML file.

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
@using TestService.ServiceReference;
@using System.Web.Helpers;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done as the `@(ViewBag.MyArray["honka"]["ponka"])` expression is evaluated on the server and then replaced by the value before it is sent to the client and the javascript is executed.

The issue is that the server needs to know these variables before rendering the page.

### Workaround 1

Pass these variables to the server via the url's querystring.

**Example razor syntax**

```
// url : ../?var1=honka&var2=ponka
$(document).ready(function () {
  var output = 'Info: @(ViewBag.MyArray[Request["var1"]][Request["var2"])';
  alert(output);
}
```

### Workaround 2

Assign the whole ViewBag.MyArray as Json to a JavasCript variable.

**Example razor syntax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var honka = "honka";
  var ponka = "ponka";
  var myArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyArray));
  var output = "Info: " + myArray[honka][ponka];
  alert(output);
}
```

Comment: So how can I resolve my issue, then? In the HTML-part of the page, I refer to the *ViewBag.MyArray* using the normal razor syntax. Please see edit.

Comment: The issue is that the server needs to know these variables before rendering the page. One workaround could be to pass these variables to the server via the url's querystring. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I won't have control over the URL, sadly. What would be a workaround here? I can keep a hidden *DIV* on the page containing a *TABLE* with the data but that's hardly a nice solution...

Comment: You could always serialize the whole ViewBag.MyArray to a json string. Once you have json, you can access anything in it using javascript.

Comment: I'll try. Since my experience of serialization using JS is close to non-existent, you're welcome to suggest a sample in your answer. Otherwise, I'll give it a whack myself but statistically speaking, I'll need to ask anyway, hehe.

Comment: This is worrying. that's the exact approach I had from the start but had to abandon it due a server-side error telling me that *Json* doesn't exist in the current context. What have I forgotten now?   :)

Comment: Do you have `@using System.Web.Helpers;` at the top of you page?

Comment: Yes. Please see the edit. I've listed what my CSHTML file starts with.